spark.sql() giving error : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: Syntax error at or near '('(line 2, pos 52)
I have class LowerCaseColumn.scala where one function is defined as below :
      override def registerSQL(): Unit = spark.sql(
        """
          |CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY FUNCTION lowerCaseColumn(inputValue STRING)
          |RETURNS STRING
          |RETURN lower(inputValue)
          |""".stripMargin)

I've one test method as below which is just trying to execute that lowerCaseColumn function using spark.sql as below but it throws error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Syntax error at or near '(' (line 2, pos 52)
test("should test if UDF got executed or not")
    {
        val sparkSessionBuilder: SparkSessionBuilder = new SparkSessionBuilder
        import sparkSessionBuilder.spark.implicits._
        val df = List("sue", "fan").toDF("input")
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("lake")
        new LowerCaseColumn(sparkSessionBuilder).registerSQL() // this throws that error
        val result = sparkSessionBuilder.spark.sql("""SELECT lowerCaseColumn(input) as result FROM lake""")
        result.show() // here an assert statements make sense

    }


The Spark create function ddl does not allow creation of ad-hoc sql functions, only registering external jars etc.
Databricks adds another syntax for sql function creation.  This is not available locally for testing.
If you need such user defined functions built through sql that work on OSS spark and on Databricks see here, e.g.:
import com.sparkutils.quality._
val rule = LambdaFunction("multValCCY", "(theValue, ccy) -> theValue * ccy", Id(1,2))
registerLambdaFunctions(Seq(rule))


thnx for your reply but I did not understand clearly. Can u pls elaborate your answer.

I'll need some information on what wasn't understood, I assume you read the links at least.

thnx for your reply. I went through the links but I am still wondering how I can run / test my SQL query (CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lowerCaseColumn, can u pls share some code snippets for me. I appreciate you shared the last link but it didn't help me actually.

you cannot locally do this with create function using OSS Spark - it is not supported.  SQL user functions only exist on databricks - this is explained in the links.  If you want to have similar sql functions the Quality lambdas exist.
